# How do I add an Advice to all implementations of AbstractMap?

Tags: byte-buddy

First time using byte-buddy.
This code block does not trigger the Advice ..

App.java

```
  AbstractMap <String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
  map.put("mykey","myvalue");
```

Agent.java

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .type(ElementMatchers.isSubTypeOf(java.util.AbstractMap.class))
                .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {

                    @Override
                    public Builder<?> transform(Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription,
                            ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule module, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain) {
                        System.out.println("In transform for AbstractMap");
                        return builder.method(ElementMatchers.any())
                                .intercept(Advice.to(MyAdvice.class));
                    }
                }).installOn(instrumentation);
```

I was expecting

```
                .type(ElementMatchers.isSubTypeOf(java.util.AbstractMap.class))
```

to call my Advice when the put/set was called on the HashMap object.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Byte Buddy ignores Java core classes. You can change this by adjusting the `ignore` matcher in the DSL of the agent builder. Be very carefull however as Byte Buddy likely uses maps and this might create loops in your code that you do not forsee.

Comment: Even with `.ignore(ElementMatchers.none())
                .type((ElementMatchers.any()))`  the advice is not getting called on set/put of the hashmap

Comment: Have you checked the log when installing a `Listener`? Is there an error logged?